# Choose cell in collection view to new controller

Tags: ios, swift, cell, collectionview

Very new to code and making a project programmatically. I have my collection view all set up but i cant figure out how to tell a specific cell to navigate to a new collection view or detail view.  Very confused and frustrated. can anyone help me or at least point me in the right direction. please dumb it down haha.

this is my main View controller

```
import UIKit



class HomeController: UICollectionViewController, 
UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {


    var Legends: [Legend] = {
    var select1 = Legend()
    select1.thumbnailImageName = "select1thumbnail"
    var select2 = Legend()
    select2.thumbnailImageName = "select2humbnail"

    return[select1, select2]        
}()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationItem.title = "Choose Selection"
    collectionView.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "backgroundlogo"))
    collectionView?.register(VideoCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellId")
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self



    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return Legends.count

}
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! VideoCell

    cell.legend = Legends[indexPath.item]       
    return cell

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width:view.frame.height, height: 150)
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0

}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let select2VC = UIViewController()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
    navigationController?.pushViewController(select2VC, animated: true)

 print("selcected")


}

}
```

this is the swift file i have for my collection view

```
import UIKit



class VideoCell: UICollectionViewCell {

var legend: Legend? {
    didSet {
        thumbnailImageView.image = UIImage(named: (legend?.thumbnailImageName)!)

    }
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupViews()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

let thumbnailImageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
    imageView.image = UIImage(named:"bgcolor")
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return imageView
}()

func setupViews() {
    addSubview(thumbnailImageView)

    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-16-[v0]-16-|", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": thumbnailImageView]))
    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-1-[v0]-0-|", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": thumbnailImageView]))

}



}
```

in a 3rd file i have just this bit of code

```
import UIKit

    class Legend: NSObject {

    var thumbnailImageName: String?

}
```

the bottom code of the main view controller does print out a "selected" but it prints it for every cell... I assume each cell will need its own viewController.swift file? then tell that cell to that swift file to show the contents?? thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you don't need to create its own `viewController.swift` file for each cell. You just need to create one detail page screen (one DetailViewController.swift) and you need to pass the detail of selected cell with variables declared on detail view controller.

Like I have done [HERE](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=04265390832244305787) in demo project with your code and result will be:

[image]

What I have done is I have added detailViewController in storyboard and also added class file. and `didSelectItemAt` will look like:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailViewController") as! DetailViewController
    controller.selectedIndex = indexPath.row //pass selected cell index to next view.
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)

}
```

Here you can pass data with `controller.selectedIndex = indexPath.row` (Herer I am passing selected index) because `selectedIndex` is a property of `DetailViewController` because I have declared it in `DetailViewController.swift` like

```
var selectedIndex = 0
```

And same way you can pass other data as well which is related with selected index.

For more info refer demo project.

Comment: omg finally hahah thank you SOOOO much... it worked, took me a bit to still get it but it worked.. You are amazing. I worked on that since 7 am to midnight yesterday. I cant thank you enough

Comment: so now that i have that all working, correct me if im wrong... i want the detailViewController to be another collection view... it would be set up basically like the HomeController but with different options and cells. would i set up the detailViewController.swift file the same as the HomeController.swift/storyboard... or is this possible?

Comment: No you can not set it up same because `HomeController` is inherited from `UICollectionViewController` and `detailViewController` is inherited from `UIViewController` but you can create new `detailViewController` which will be inherited from `UICollectionViewController` same as your `HomeController`

Comment: Hm.  Aright. Makes sense...... I may just rethink my detail view.  Thank you again.

Comment: Happy to help you.. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want check what is sell pressed. You can check what is type cell pressed:

```
if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? VideoCell {
//check some property and go to new UIViewController or UICollectionViewController
//and transfer data 
}
```